# can we put another phrase instead of 'which'?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am having below ideas but not sure what is the best way to express them. May be both might wrong.

> 1. Most of previous approaches *on the use of point data* typically have
>      been focused on the forest applications.
> 2. Most of previous approaches *which use point data* typically have been
>      focused on the forest applications.

So, my problem is can I use *on the use of point data* instead of *which use point data* to tell my idea or at least my 2nd sentence is grammatically meaningful or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically incorrect and verbose.

> 1. Most approaches using point data were typically focused on forest applications.
> 2. Most approaches that used point data were typically focused on forest applications.

Using "of" requires "the": "Most of the approaches..."

"Previous" is superfluous because the sentences are in the past tense. If those approaches are still used, however, the verb should be in the present tense, and maybe the sentences should say something like this:

> A. Most (other [*This assumes that you're introducing a new approach*]) approaches using point data are typically focused on forest applications.

or this:

> B. Most (other) approaches that use point data are typically focused on forest applications.

Perhaps, however, the sentences should read something like this:

> C. Most other approaches are typically focused on using point data in forests.

Without knowing what *point data* are, and without knowing what *forest applications* are, it's difficult to give a definitive answer. These are just guesses.

Comment: +1 And I'd suggest that either 'most' or 'typically' needs to go - preferably 'typically', so that word can be reserved for uses where it actually means 'characteristic of the type'.